# Creating a plist with multiple strings

Tags: objective-c, macos, plist

I have a multiple strings I would like to write to one plist using objective c. Can anyone please tell me exactly how to do this? I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

As H2CO3 hinted, you could use `NSArray`'s [`writeToFile:atomically:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABCGEFF) method.

For example:

```
NSArray *arr = @[
    @"my first string",
    @"my second string",
    @"and the last one"
];
[arr writeToFile:@"./out.plist" atomically:NO]; // Or YES depending on your needs
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility:

```
// Create the path that you want to write your plist to.
NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *documentsURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:&error];
if (documentsURL == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error finding user documents in directory: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return nil;
}
NSString *path = [[documentsURL path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourFile.plist"];

// Populate your strings and save to the plist specified in the above path.
NSString *kRoot = @"kRoot"; 
NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
tempDict[kRoot] = [NSMutableArray array];
[tempDict[kRoot] addObject:@"String 1"];
[tempDict[kRoot] addObject:@"String 2"];
[tempDict[kRoot] addObject:@"String 3"];
// Etc, add all your strings
if (![tempDict writeToFile:path atomically:YES])
{
    NSLog(@"Error writing data to path %@", path);
}
```

Comment: That's the wrong way to check an error condition in Cocoa. It must be `if (documentsURL == nil)`.

Comment: In Cocoa errors are passed back to the caller by reference. But the fact that an error occurred must be transported by other means, typically the return value. The called method has the right to set the error to anything, even if no error occurred.

Comment: Here's a reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I've edited my answer to reflect more correct error handling.